# Visualisation of database object dependencies

Tags: dependencies, oracle-database

I'm searching for a tool to visualize dependencies between all kinds of Oracle database objects (tables, views, triggers, scheduler jobs, packages/functions/procedures & direct and indirect grants).

The tool should connect to the database and either be able to generate a diagram/graph out of the database state or enable the user to navigate through some kind of interactive dependency navigator.

(If possible, the tool should also enable the user to add additional information into the graph/diagram e.g. additional dependency connections, comments, ... without having to alter the database)

An example diagram could look something like this:

[image: example dependency diagram]

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, and not updated for quite a while – but coming close: [HyperSQL](https://codeberg.org/izzy/HyperSQL) works on the `*.sql` files used to create a database schema's objects, and can be enriched with JavaDoc like comments. Uses Graphviz to generate the graphics. Also see [HyperSQL automatically documents SQL code](https://sourceforge.net/blog/hypersql-automatically-documents-sql-code/) for an independent intro ;) (disclosure: I was the maintainer of the project for several years)